# Is it possible to get performance counter description using Powershell command get-counter?

Tags: powershell, performancecounter, perfmon

On Windows, we can easily get the description of a performance counter by using the `perfmon` utility. Take a look at the *description* section in below snapshot.

[image]

Is it possible to get this info from Powershell's `get-counter` cmdlet?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this one, but so far all I've found is descriptions for counter sets, not the individual counters themselves. I'm not sure if that information is baked inside of perfmon, or if it's stored in a dictionary inside a dll somewhere, or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that information is stored in the registry at (for English):

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009 in the multi-string key Help

So since PowerShell can use the Registry as a Provider, yes you can get this information technically although it's a bit ugly:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009").Help
```

That will pull all the text from the help entry, which you can then filter through with pipes/Select-String/various string methods, Where clauses/etc.